# Passing parameter id onto another page

Tags: java, spring, parameter-passing

I want to pass the id of the student from the display.jsp table in to my student.jsp. I have problem getting the id of the student. I can't get to display or get its values. Please do help. Thanks

Here is my jdbc to select the id

```
public Student getStudentInfo(String id) {
        String SQL = "SELECT * FROM student WHERE id = ?";
        Event student = jdbcTemplateObject.queryForObject(SQL, new Object[] {id}, new StudentMapper());
        return student;

    }
```

display.jsp. Table of Student Info containing the id i want to pass

```
   <tbody>
        <c:forEach var="studentinfo" items="${display}">
    <tr>
    <td><c:out value="${studentinfo.id}"/></td>
    <td><c:out value="${studentinfo.name}"/></td>
    <td><c:out value="${studentinfo.age}"/></td>
    <td><c:out value="${studentinfo.bday}"/></td>
    <td><c:out value="${studentinfo.address}"/></td>
    <td><button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" name="deleteButton" value="${studentinfo.event_id}" onClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this student information?')"><i class="fa fa-times"></i>Delete</button>
<td>
<a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/student?id=${studentinfo.id}"><c:out value="${studentinfo.id}"/></a>
</td>
</td>
</tr>
 </c:forEach>
</tbody>
```

My Controller

```
@RequestMapping("/student")
    public String studentinfo(HttpServletRequest request, ModelMap model){

        try
        {
        StudentJDBC = (Student)context.getBean("studentJDBC");
        System.out.println(request.getParameter("id"));
        studentJDBC.getStudentInfo(request.getParameter("id"));
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.print(e);
        }

        return "student";
    }
```

And i want to display it from this jsp

```
<html>
<body>
<label>Student Id</label>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <span class="input-icon">
                                <span class="input-icon">
                                <input name="id" value="${studentinfo.id}"/>
                                </span>
                        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It looks like you do not have studentinfo object on the final page. Check if you are setting it in the page context or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not adding your queried data to the new model/ request. Hence when you are doing a `<c:forEach>` on `${display}`, it is empty. And also, your display should be a list as per your UI code, having student elements.

Comment: this is what i get. idorg.springframework.dao.EmptyResultDataAccessException: Incorrect result size: expected 1, actual 0

Comment: Check what is the id you are passing. It might have no data in database with the id you are querying.